# Add-Migration makes a mistake - wrong constraint column name?

Tags: entity-framework, data-migration

I'm trying to create a database migration by

```
PM> Add-Migration
...
PM> Update-Database
...
```

but all I get is an error message telling me that an invalid column is referenced. It gets clear when you look at the generated migration which contains the following Up() method:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Bestelllistes", name: "Ersteller_Id", newName: "PodioUser_Id");
        AddColumn("dbo.Bestelllistes", "ErstelltDatum", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Bestelllistes", "ZuletztModifiziertDatum", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Bestelllistes", "ZuletztModifiziertDurch_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Bestelllistes", "Ersteller_Id", "dbo.PodioUsers", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Bestelllistes", "ZuletztModifiziertDurch_Id", "dbo.PodioUsers", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Bestelllistes", "Ersteller_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Bestelllistes", "ZuletztModifiziertDurch_Id");
    }
```

RenameColumn contradicts AddForeignKey which still uses the old constraint column name. I could manually change this, but I'm afraid that's not the way it's ought to work.

Is this usual behaviour or is it a bug? Looks like one to me.

//edit: Ah, just to explain what I did before that: I added another <strike>column</strike> property referencing the dbo.PodioUsers table to the "Bestellliste" model. So now "Bestellliste" has got two properties referencing the "PodioUser" model.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me, too. It seems to happen when I add the `[Required]` attribute to a field that didn't have it before.

To work around the issue I use `update-database -force -script`, edit the SQL and run it against the DB. In my case that's MSSQL and I use the Management Studio for that.